# setting up shiny server for the web

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I got my shiny server on a virtual box running ubuntu. Everything works fine and I can access my app locally.

Now I want to enable user to access my shiny server through the web, but I have no idea how to set this up in ubuntu. I could not find any article about this step. Does anyone can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As it stands, this post is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants to know the solution. Set the network seetings of the virtual box on network bridge and then use port forwarding to the shiny server, usually 3838

Comment: Great! Next time try to formulate your question so that it shows research effort and that you have tried something.